# Breakdown of latency and packet loss in different switches of the network

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, mininet

In my mininet network, I have three switches, where I calculated latency, throughput, link utilization, packet loss, and jitter.
Now I want to break down the latency and packet loss results for every switch. For example, if I ping a network with 10 packets from host1(residing in switch 1) to host8(residing in switch 3) and total packet loss is 20%, two packets are lost from out of 10. Now I am trying to figure out from which switch packets are lost either from switch1,switch2, or switch.
*** h1 : ('ping -w 10', '10.0.0.8', '>', 'ping_h1.out', '2>', 'ping_h1.err')

- icmp_seq=1
- icmp_seq=2
- icmp_seq=4
- icmp_seq=5
- icmp_seq=7
- icmp_seq=8
- icmp_seq=9
- icmp_seq=10

('loss: ', '3') ('loss: ', '6')

Packet Loss:  20% packet loss
I want to know from which switches icmp_seq = 3 and icmp_seq = 6 are lost means that two packets were lost.

Finally, in my network total latency is 9.6ms and I want to break down the whole latency for three different switches.

It would be great if anyone could give me any suggestions to figure this out, whether by using mininet of other simulation tools.

Comment: I suggest you use a network management application rather than trying to design this yourself.

Comment: Can you pls suggest one of the network management applications? I need to do the simulation of the network and I am doing it using mininet.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with network monitoring applications. Try asking on [sf]

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._"